# Selenium to click on the title from a drop down menu

Tags: c#, selenium

I am in middle of a selenium application development using C#. I have a drop down menu on a webpage. I want selenium to click on the exact name after clicking the drop down menu. I am successful on clicking drop down menu now and I can view the titles or options on that menu.

What I want is that I need selenium to click on the title based on what the user gave when the application is first opened. Actually the menu button is not visible, but when I make mouse hover the name, it is visible.

[image: Menu Button]

I have tried

```
var menu = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ms-vb"));
SelectElement sel = new SelectElement(menu); 
sel.SelectByText(text);
```

where text is the user entered text. While running the app it throws an error like

"Element should have been select but was img"

How can I solve this??My task is onhold due to this..

Any comments will be really appreciated..

Thanks

**HTML**

I hope this is the code that you require:

```html
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" height="100%" onmouseover="OnMouseOverFilter(this)" class="ms-unselectedtitle"
sortfields="SortField=Unify%5fx0020%5fApp&amp;SortDir=Asc&amp;View=%7b696D6B29%2d5A5D%2d47F3%2d97CF%2dECBFDD1E2CE8%7d"
resulttype="" fieldtype="Lookup" displayname="Unify App" ctxnum="1" name="Unify_x0020_App" filterable="" filterdisable=""
sortdisable="" sortable="" style="width:100%;" id="msomenuid2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-vb">
        <a sortingfields="SortField=Unify%5fx0020%5fApp&amp;SortDir=Asc&amp;View=%7b696D6B29%2d5A5D%2d47F3%2d97CF%2dECBFDD1E2CE8%7d"
        onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" href="javascript:" title="Sort by Unify App"
        onfocus="OnFocusFilter(this)" id="diidSortUnify_x0020_App">Unify App
        <img width="1" border="0" height="1" alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." class="ms-hidden"
        src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" /></a>
        <img border="0" alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" />
        <img border="0" alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" />
      </td>
      <td style="position: absolute; right: 1px;" class="">
        <img width="13px" alt="Open Menu" style="visibility: hidden;" src="/_layouts/images/menudark.gif" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: We will need to see the HTML of the page to begin any kind of diagnosing, also clarify what you mean when you say "title based on what the user gave when the app is first opened" -> app as in what? Your website?

Comment: @Arran: I mean like I have a dialog box designed for asking the user to enter a title. I need selenium to check whether any entry is there in the webpage with the user entered title.

Regarding html, did you mean to get you the html code of that drop down button??

Comment: Of the dropdown button and what surrounds it - so we can see exactly how it sits in the DOM.

Comment: @Arran:Please find my edited answer for HTML..Hope you require this one only..

Comment: Well the `SelectElement` is expecting a `select` element, which is used to represent dropdown's in HTML. Your `FindElement(By.ClassName("ms-vb"))` is giving it an `img`, so I'd suggest you take a look at the whole page, and ensure that there are no other elements with a class of `ms-vb` ...to do this, simply run `driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("ms-vb"))` ...how many come back?

Comment: @Arran: Actually that is also a problem. There are many with the same class name. In fact I couldn't find any unique attribute for this rather than a "textContent" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a normal  element the SelectElement class will not work.

This is how I deal with javascript dropdowns:

```
    //Click on the dropdown
    driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ms-vb")).Click();
    //Wait for the result list to appear
    wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.LinkText("Target link to click")));
    //Click on the result you want
    driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Target link to click")).Click();
```

If the result is not a link  you should use xPath to locate it by its text. Ex.

```
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='Target text']")).Click();
```

Hope it helps.